# Twitter Bootstrap Tab Navigation - links fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, tabs, navigation, twitter-bootstrap-3

Rails 4, Ruby 2.0

We have a tabs navigation menu on the right hand side but when you click into any of the containers and load the content, the top link to the main page (Kit Jacket) stops working.

To reproduce:

Click any of the "More" links in any container.
Content loads in the window.
Top level link to main page "Kit Jacket" will not work. 
Click any other of the navigation links in the right nav window.
Content loads in the window.
How the top level link to "Kit Jacket" works.

The same behavior happens with the Bio section, which is not in the tabbed pane.

We used the bootstrap tab markup method without using additional JavaScript (data-toggle="tab")

Page: http://www.entreuse.com/demos

Git repo: https://github.com/jaysonperry/entreuseApp/blob/master/app/views/kit/deanorion.html.erb

```
  <div class="kit-content-list">
            <h4>In this Kit</h4>
            <ul class="nav nav-stacked" id="kitContentList">
              <li class="active">
                <!-- <a href="#jacket" data-toggle="tab">Kit Jacket</a> -->
                <%= link_to "Kit Jacket", '#jacket', :data => {:toggle=>"tab"} %>
              </li>
              <li>
                <!-- <a href="#pressRelease01" data-toggle="tab">Press Release</a> -->
                <%= link_to "Press Release", '#pressRelease01', :data => {:toggle=>"tab"} %>
              </li>
              <li>
                <!-- <a href="#bookSummary" data-toggle="tab">Book Summary</a> -->
                <%= link_to 'Book Summary', '#bookSummary', :data => {:toggle=>"tab"} %>
              </li>
              <li>
                <!-- <a href="#bookOneSheet" data-toggle="tab">Book One-Sheet</a> -->
                <%= link_to 'Book One-Sheet', '#bookOneSheet', :data => {:toggle=>"tab"} %>
              </li>
              <li>
                <!-- <a href="#blogReviews" data-toggle="tab">Bloggers Reviews</a> -->
                <%= link_to 'Bloggers Reviews', '#blogReviews', :data => {:toggle=>"tab"} %>
              </li>
              <li>
                <!-- <a href="#amazonReviews" data-toggle="tab">Amazon Reviews</a> -->
                <%= link_to 'Amazon Reviews', '#amazonReviews', :data => {:toggle=>"tab"} %>
              </li>
              <li>
                <!-- <a href="#interviewQAs" data-toggle="tab">Interview Q & A's</a> -->
                <%= link_to 'Interview Q & A\'s', '#interviewQAs', :data => {:toggle=>"tab"} %>
              </li>
              <li>
                <!-- <a href="#bioAuthor" data-toggle="tab">Dean Orion Biography</a> -->
                <%= link_to 'Dean Orion Biography', '#bioAuthor', :data => {:toggle=>"tab"} %>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click a link on the right hand side, Bootstrap is setting the class `.active` to the parent `<li>` of that link. Aside from providing a hook for styling, this prevents Bootstrap from firing the fade out/in animation if you were to click that link again.

The issue is that - because you are triggering the tab outside of that group of tabs, Bootstrap does not remove the `.active` class. See the image below for what I am talking about.

[image: image of code]

Remove this class, and your "Kit Jacket" link will work again. There are two main ways I can suggest handling the removal.

1. Add a listener to your "more..." link that removes the active class. This could be a bit tricky, and actually conflict with the listener Bootstrap is adding via the `data-toggle` attribute.
2. Don't use the `data-toggle` attribute on the "more..." link at all. Instead, create a listener that fires the click action for your "Press Release" link. Add an ID to your "more..."  and "Press Release" link, and then do something like:

   ```
   $('#morelink').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#pressrelease').click();
   }
   ```

Comment: I did not fully follow the javaScript solution, could not make it work; however, with a big smile, once I knew it that the .active class was not removed by links outside the .nav list proper. So I came up with a solution, not the elegant one, but a solution nonetheless: I simple refresh the page when the Kit Jacket link is clicked in the menu list-but it is in its own name space. The content is already in the cache so the refresh is virtually instantaneous.  I really want to get a handle on the more pro way of doing it like yours. Do you have any references to point me towards for study? Thx